# Excel: Finding difference between 2 columns when rows are not matched

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A: 1000 unique names

Column B: A number corresponding with each name in A

Column C: Same 1000 names as A (different order than A, since values in D have changed)

Column D: A number for each name from C (numbers have changed from B)

At the moment, A/B and C/D are sorted from largest to smallest.

I want to create column E with the same 1000 names, but sorted by the difference between the values corresponding with each name from columns B and D. That Difference will be in column F.

Some values have changed a lot, so a name at the top of the column A may be way down the list in column C.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

column E:

```
(copy of column A)
```

column F:

```
=vlookup(E1,A:B,2,false)-vlookup(E1,C:D,2,false)
```

Then sort E:F on F.

Extra notes by fixer1234

Comment: For some reason after i sort on F, it then immediately unsorts after a split second

Comment: back to the same order as column A

Comment: @charu, it sounds like you missed the step about copy/paste-special values.  Col F should contain nothing but numbers, so there's no basis for the sort to change to anything else.  If they still contain formulas, the formulas will update.

Comment: @charu, if you want to sort it, you'll have to highlight both column E&F, and paste as values in G&H, then sort H. If no point in directly sorting column F since the content is formulas (the same for all column F cell).. not values (that we normally sort with..).

Comment: @fixer1234 column A and B have the same order, F does contain nothing but numbers

Comment: @p._phidot_ i was hoping to be able to see that biggest changers automatically depending on how i changed how the numbers in B and D are produced

Comment: @charu, If it's resorting, it sounds like col E is still showing =A1.  No matter how you sort E and F, E will still point to the same order as A.  Instead of =A1, just copy and paste the col A values in col E to get the list there.  Then in col F use `=vlookup(E1,A:B,2,false)-vlookup(E1,C:D,2,false)`.  Then sort E:F on F.  If the values in B or D change, you will need to resort E:F because sorts don't automatically update.  Otherwise, you will need VBA to automatically resort.

Comment: @Brian, If charu reports back that my suggestion worked, feel free to edit it into your answer.  The requirements in the question weren't clear and you already provided the gist of the answer the same way I read it.